# pyOpenSSL signature verification using Python 3

Tags: digital-signature, python-3.4, verify, pyopenssl

I am trying to verify a signature using pyOpenSSL with Python 3.4.2. Here is my code.

```
from OpenSSL import crypto

some_byte_string = b'This is a byte string.'
crt = crypto.load_certificate(crypto.FILETYPE_PEM, pem)

# self.signature is a base64 encoded string
crypto.verify(crt, self.signature, some_byte_string, 'sha1')
```

That produces the following exception:

```
verify_result = _lib.EVP_VerifyFinal(md_ctx, signature, len(signature), pkey)
TypeError: initializer for ctype 'unsigned char *' must be a bytes or list or tuple, not str
```

I have also tried using a regular string for 'some_byte_string' but I get the following exception when I try that:

```
_lib.EVP_VerifyUpdate(md_ctx, data, len(data))
TypeError: initializer for ctype 'void *' must be a cdata pointer, not str
```

I saw a previous SO question that referenced the [unittest for pyOpenSSL verify](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~exarkun/pyopenssl/trunk/view/head:/OpenSSL/test/test_crypto.py#L2838) and this appears to be what I am doing though obviously something is wrong.

Edit:
Forgot to mention the version of pyOpenSSL I am using is pyOpenSSL-0.14-py3.4.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently it's a bug with 0.14 and will be fixed in 0.15.

https://github.com/pyca/pyopenssl/issues/15